# Unity Creating Array Of Buttons from Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime-error

I'm working on an in game tilemap editor, and I'm creating a menu of tiles that players can select to place on the map. I have these split into families of tiles/enemies, and I'm attempting to create the buttons for these menus by instantiating a button prefab many times, and changing each button's sprite and other properties. Here's what the code looks like for adding the buttons:

```cs
void CreateButtons()
{
    for (int i=0;i<prefabNames.Length;i++)
    {
        Button button = Instantiate<Button>(prefabButtonPrefab);
        GameObject prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/" + prefabNames[i]);
        button.image.sprite = prefab.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
                
        button.GetComponent<EditorPrefabUIController>().prefabName = prefabNames[i];

       //LINE 51 buttons[i] = button;
    }      
}
```

When this runs however, I'm getting a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at line 51 (assigning the Button to the list). The buttonPrefab has been set with a Prefab that is a button though, so I'm not sure where this error is coming from.

I've tried switching the prefab to be a gameObject, and getting the Button Component from that instead, but the same error arises. Am I missing something?

Edit:Additonal Info. The Resources are loading fine, as I was able to Debug to see the prefab loaded with the proper components. Here's what the button prefab looks like that I've assigned to this script in the editor

[ButtonPrefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfQgW.png)

Comment: Without more information like what is the 51 line, what your other code is doing and even how you have assigned the prefab .. It is hard tell where the problem really is. Did you put the `prefab` that you are getting from `Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/" + prefabNames[i])` correct (prefabs need to be in a folder named `Resources` in your Assets folder are you doing that ? show your second prefab location